# error in sending url encoded data through curl php

Tags: php, post, curl

here is my php code for CURL post:

```
$post = array("field1"=>"data1%%Fval","field2"=>"data2%%12 Add");

$fields = "";

$i = 0;
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
$fields .= ($i > 0) ? "&" . "$key=" . urlencode($value) : "$key=" .    urlencode($value);
$i++;
};

set_time_limit(60);
$output = array();
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$rawresponse = curl_exec($curlSession);
```

when i post url encoded data through php CURL using above code then i don't get URL encoded data at server end where i receive data as post.

it seems my code has any problem which automatically performing URL decode before sending data.

can anyone please tell me the solution for this problem?

Comment: Fyi.. PHP will automatically urldecode `$_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST` by default

Comment: Yes, you don't need to decode url while reading parameters.

Comment: Also you don't need to urlencode POST data. Just pass `$post` array as is to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option